# persons.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am re-learning react after a break and I am confused as to why my .map function gives me an error code after trying to add data to the state displayed. I don't know if I am calling the function improperly or I have made an error while trying to add new data into the array.

Here is my code. It has an event handler, on submit action and display.

```
 import React, { useState } from 'react'
 import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

 const App = () => {
 const [ persons, setPersons ] = useState([
  { id:1, name: 'Arto Hellas' }
 ]) 
 const [ newName, setNewName ] = useState('')

 const addPerson = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault()
  console.log('button clicked',event.target)
  const personObject = {
    name:newName,
    // date: new Date().toISOString(),
     id: persons.length +1,
  }
  setPersons(persons.concat(personObject))
  setPersons('')
 }

 const handlePersonChange = (event)=>{
    console.log(event.target.value)
    if(persons.name===event.target.value){
      alert(event.target.value," is already on the list")
    }else setNewName(event.target.value)
 }
 const displayName = ()=> persons.map(p=>
   <li key={p.id}>{p.name}</li>
 )



 return (
   <div>
     <h2>Phonebook</h2>
     <form onSubmit={addPerson}>
       <div>
        name: <input value={newName}  onChange={handlePersonChange}/>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button type="submit">add</button>
      </div>
    </form>
    <h2>Numbers</h2>
    <ul>
      {displayName()}
    </ul>
  </div>
  )
  }


 ReactDOM.render(
  <App  />,
  document.getElementById('root')
 )
```

Comment: `setPersons('')` — You're setting it to an empty string!

Comment: The concat method returns a new array : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it has something to do with this piece of code :

```
  setPersons(persons.concat(personObject))
  setPersons('')
```

You are setting your persons state to a string so map method cannot be applied to it.